# VBA to change cell color when double clicked and then change it back when double clicked again

Tags: vba

My current code changes cell color to yellow with a single click and then changes it back to nothing when clicked again. I was wondering if I can do that this time changing it to green (Color Index = 10) when double clicked and then back to nothing when double clicked again. Here's my current code:

`Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
    Cancel = True
    Worksheet_SelectionChange target
End Sub`

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal target As Range)If 
Intersect(target, Range("B9:AF129")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    If target.Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone Then
        target.Interior.ColorIndex = 6
    ElseIf target.Interior.ColorIndex = 6 Then
        target.Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: you did not say whether the code works or not ... it has a syntax error as it is written, so it does not even execute

Comment: You cannot re-use your SelectionChange event code, since it has no way to distinguish between click/double-click.

Comment: This will be tricky since a double-click also fires the SelectionChange event...

Comment: @jsotola sorry, yeah my code works

Comment: @kemichan: The event `Worksheet_SelectionChange` fires **irregardless** of what caused the selection change: mouse click, up/down/left/right/page up... etc., or VBA code (like `Range("A2").Select`). How on earth do you plan to react ONLY TO A MOUSE CLICK without using API functionality?! And if you are to go that route then there will be no question like this one of yours, right?

Answer (score 0):

Sort-of works...

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
    Cancel = ToggleColor(target, vbGreen)
    Debug.Print "double"

End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal target As Range)
    ToggleColor target, vbYellow
    Debug.Print "single"
End Sub

Private Function ToggleColor(rng As Range, clr As Long) As Boolean

    If Intersect(rng, Me.Range("B9:AF129")) Is Nothing Then Exit Function
    If rng.Cells.CountLarge > 1 Then Exit Function

    With rng.Interior
        If .ColorIndex = xlNone Or .Color <> clr Then
            .Color = clr
        Else
            .ColorIndex = xlNone
        End If
    End With

    ToggleColor = True 'to cancel the double-click
End Function
```

Comment: single click turns it yellow, double click - green. to turn it back to white, you gotta click it back to yellow and then white? Was it meant to be like that? :)